# Python - Pandas remove rows after self-join (merge)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

Kind similar to this question: [Pandas merge removing duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590900/pandas-merge-removing-duplicate-rows)

I am using Python pandas -

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
               'type':['a','b','c','d','e'],
               'value':[100,200,300,400,500]})
```

I want to self-join this list:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df, df,on=['type'])
```

But I want only want to keep rows below:

```
type_x  value_x type_y  value_y
a       100      b      200
a       100      c      300
a       100      d      400
a       100      e      500
b       200      c      300
b       200      d      400
b       200      e      500
c       300      d      400
c       300      e      500
d       400      e      500
```

How can I do this in Pandas? Thank you for the help!

Comment: I don't think the outer join does what you are expecting. Have you tried running the code you posted? The rows you describe should not appear in df_merge.

The output you want looks more like the result of itertools.combinations.

Comment: Agree - any thoughts on how to use itertools? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but gets the job done:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
               'type':['a','b','c','d','e'],
               'value':[100,200,300,400,500]})

import itertools
combinations = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df['type'], 2)), columns=['type_x', 'type_y'])

combinations = pd.merge(combinations, df, left_on='type_x', right_on='type') \
                    .drop(columns=['type']) \
                    .rename(columns={'value': 'value_x'})
combinations = pd.merge(combinations, df, left_on='type_y', right_on='type') \
                    .drop(columns=['type']) \
                    .rename(columns={'value': 'value_y'})
combinations
```

|  | type_x | type_y | value_x | value_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | a | c | 100 | 300 |
| 2 | b | c | 200 | 300 |
| 3 | a | d | 100 | 400 |
| 4 | b | d | 200 | 400 |
| 5 | c | d | 300 | 400 |
| 6 | a | e | 100 | 500 |
| 7 | b | e | 200 | 500 |
| 8 | c | e | 300 | 500 |
| 9 | d | e | 400 | 500 |

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for pandas.merge() here. Just feed the combinations output into the DataFrame constructor (with a little sleight of hand to turn two 2-tuples into a list with 4 elements):

```
from itertools import combinations
import pandas

types = ['a','b','c','d','e']
values = [100,200,300,400,500]

rows = [[*pair1, *pair2] 
        for pair1, pair2 in combinations(zip(types, values), 2)]

columns = [f"{col}_{var}" 
           for col in ['type', 'value'] 
           for var in ['x', 'y']]

pandas.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)
```